# SQL query to select an element in a column which has relation to some different elements in other column?

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

It is quite difficult to describe my question by this title.

I have three tables, they relate to others with primary keys and foreign keys as below :

```
 student(*student_id*, first_name, last_name, dob, gender, address, note, clazz_id)
 subject(*subject_id*, name, credit, percentage_final_exam)
 enrollment(*student_id, subject_id, semester*, midterm_score, final_score)
```

Question: give a list of students who enrolled **in both** "Java Programming" and "Embedded Programming"

The result should include `student_id, subject_id, subject_name, semester`.
I've been thinking about the division of two relations but I don't know how to do it.
Can somebody have me implement it or maybe in another better way?
Many thanks!

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I'm quite new to SQL. Division is the only idea I can think of. I've searched google but the way to do it is quite complex, not to mention the case of multiple tables

Comment: I think about join three tables then divide to the table of subject_id of those two subjects

Comment: You can join to the same table in a query multiple times, with different join criteria (or different filters in the WHERE clause). Can you see how that might be useful here?

Comment: I am not really clear with your suggestion. I've been stuck with this problem for a few days already. It's very great if you have a clear solution

Comment: Do it step by step. First JOIN two of the tables. Does the result make sense? If it does, JOIN the third table. Does this result make sense? Etc.

Comment: A further hint - if you can create a query to select students that have taken course A, you can add two more joins to limit those results to just those students that have taken both courses A _and_ B. This will involve joining against both enrollment and subject twice.